# What are the most important advantages of using flexbox instead of just using display: inline

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float, inline

I know that it is far more comfortable to use flexbox instead of old concepts like

`display: inline;`
`float: right`

But when you compare using flexbox just by putting a container and using `display: flex;` instead of just changing every element inside the container to `display: inline;`, what are the advantaged of using flexbox? I mean **apart from using** things like direction, wrap, justify-content etc.

So when I give an example like [image: display in this image]

Can I also achieve those properties (one item horizontally put after another within the container, together fitting the total container size) by using `display:inline` and `float: right`?

I know that this is ineffective. But I am searching for arguments why flexbox is a good alternative to the old inline/float-approach, even if you only use flexbox's main abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*...arguments why flexbox is a good alternative to the old inline/float-approach...*

> **Why Flexbox?**
>
> For a long time, the only reliable cross-browser compatible tools
> available for creating CSS layouts were features like floats and
> positioning. These work, but in some ways they're also limiting and
> frustrating.
>
> The following simple layout designs are either difficult or impossible
> to achieve with such tools in any kind of convenient, flexible way:
>
> - Vertically centering a block of content inside its parent.
> - Making all the children of a container take up an equal amount of the available    width/height, regardless of how much width/height is
>   available.
> - Making all columns in a multiple-column layout adopt the same height     even if they contain a different amount of content.

[MDN flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)